# Turning off test-output in TestNG

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, testng

I am currently launching my suit of tests using this XML file:

```
<suite name="something">
    <test name="generic valid compilation">
        <parameter name="isValid" value="true"/>
        <parameter name="testGroup" value="generic"/>
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="compilation"></include>
                <exclude name="module"></exclude>
                <exclude name="refinement"></exclude>
                <exclude name="specifications"></exclude>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="test.TestLauncher"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

and I am looking for a way to cut off the generated test-output folder that TestNG seems to do by default. From http://reportng.uncommons.org/ I can see that

> You may also want to disable the
>   default TestNG reporters by setting
>   the useDefaultListeners attribute to
>   "false".

which seems to suit my needs, wouldn't it be the fact that their XML structure seems different than mine.

Does anybody know how to turn the test output files off with TestNG?

Thanks

Comment: To do this programatically, view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041967/java-turn-off-testngs-default-reporters-programatically/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like you said, just use this flag to turn off the default reports. The exact name depends on whether you're using the command line, ant or maven. Look this string up in the documentation that is relevant to you.

Comment: I am just clicking in this XML and in Run As -> TestNG Suite (in Eclipse). I see no place other than the above XML to put that option. I've tried puting it there but it woudln't make a difference.

Comment: Add a `-usedefaultlisteners false` in the Arguments box of your launch configuration.

Comment: Is there a way to do this programatically?

Comment: For anyone trying to figure out how to do this from the Maven command line, I found this post really helpful: http://rolf-engelhard.de/2011/05/avoid-creation-of-emailable-report-html-when-using-maven-surefire-and-testng/

Answer (score 8):

If you are starting tests from command line use `–useDefaultListeners false`:

```
java org.testng.TestNG –useDefaultListeners false testng.xml
```

If you want to do it programmatically:

```
TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
testNG.setUseDefaultListeners(false);
...
```

Answer (score 4):

I just clean it afterwards :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <filesets>
            <fileset>
                <directory>test-output</directory>
                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
            </fileset>
        </filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

in **Eclipse** you could check that option to avoid it:
Windows --> Preferences--> TestNG

[Disable default listeners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOgjp.png)

Comment: Hello, as mentioned by the requester, diabling default listener could not fit its context since the xml structure does not comply with it. Please may you convert your reply as a comment to the question. Maybe other users could realy find it useful if they are in your context