# How do I disable the test-out folder

Tags: maven, testng

Would like to disable the test-out folder means test outputs in my project as it less disk space issues in automation machines. Tried all below options as got it our tool:

1. SetDefaultListener(false);
2. setVerbose(0);
3. command line argument -usedefaultListener false

nothing can work me.I am using maven build tool to generate the jar. We need to give the jar to automachines to run this.

Comment: Which `test-out` directory are you talking about?

Comment: may this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751416/turning-off-test-output-in-testng

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible by definition if do not want to have that folders, you have to skip tests in process of Jar building.

Comment: Thanks Gin-Tried to skip test process while building the jar.even we are seeng test-folder creation after running the testscripts.

Comment: Am trying to avoid test-folder or test outputs while running the validation in testNG.

Comment: do you execute clean before starting tests ?