# -usedefaultlisteners treated as file when supplied as command line argument to testNG

Tags: java, testng

Sorry if this question has already been answered some where, I have not had any luck turning up a solution. This is my first SO post, if information is missing/unclear, or the formatting sucks, let me know, I will update the post.

I am using TestNG version 6.13.1 (also tested with 7.0.0-beta1). I am running this command (not the full command, the class path is massive, and there are multiple -D options)

```
java -cp <classpath stuff...> -DappiumPort=30000 org.testng.TestNG -usedefaultlisteners false /Users/.../adbservice/test-results/3567/test_config/Test_Suite_testT13googleMaps.xml
```

*expecting that testNG will recognize the first argument as a switch, and turn the default listeners off*. This is based on reading [Turning off test-output in TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751416/turning-off-test-output-in-testng) and http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml, and other less relevant documents.

*What actually happens is testNG appears to treat all the arguments as if they are file paths*, and I get a very helpful error message

```
ProcessResults(exitCode=0, output=java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/.../adbservice/-usedefaultlisteners false testng.xml (No such file or directory)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:196)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:139)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:148)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:233)
at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:290)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:334)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeEverything(TestNG.java:974)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:988)
at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1330)
at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1299)
```

The command itself is issued from Java, using a wrapper around a ProcessExecutor. The code looks like

```
new ProcessExecutor()
            .command(cmd)
            .readOutput(true)
            .timeout(waitForTimeMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .execute();
```

I can get the same error if I capture the command input and paste it into the shell, so it seems that it is not a problem with the java code itself, but I figured I would include that information for completeness.

My question is, how can I make this call to testNG work using the command line arguments? There seem to be few alternatives because I have packaged tests which are executed in a shell process.

**Edit**
Since this is such a common case, I am convinced there is something wrong on my side. I tested that theory out by creating a really simple java project with a smoke test, and then ran it with

```
java -cp .:testng-6.13.1.jar:jcommander-1.72.jar:build/libs/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.testng.TestNG -usedefaultlisteners false testng.xml
```

which worked exactly as described in the documentation. Therefore I think there is something going on with the input to java and how it is being processed that is causing the error with testNG.

**Edit 2**
Did some further investigation on my side, eventually I tried the original generated java command with the parameters ( -usedefaultlisteners false) on the command line, and lo and behold it worked, or at least, it did some stuff before bombing out, instead of complaining about the parameters being invalid file paths, which was my original result when running on the command line. Maybe I had the wrong directory or some such the first time, but this suggests that it *is* a problem with handling the command with this ProcessExecutor.

**Edit 3**
Paydirt. It turns out the ProcessExecutor library does not handle command line input with spaces as one might expect, so for example,

```
Lists.newArrayList(
    "java", "-cp", ".:", "org.testng.TestNG", "-enabledefaultlisteners false", "testng.xml"
)
```

will error, but

```
Lists.newArrayList(
    "java", "-cp", ".:", "org.testng.TestNG", "-enabledefaultlisteners", "false", "testng.xml"
)
```

works. It seems like that should be documented in the ProcessExecutor library docs.